# Jade to HTML converter

Tags: html, converters, pug

I have started writing an application using nodejs and jade, but after a while my team decided to switch to Django. I would still like to use the web pages written using jade, without having to re-write them by hand.

Does anyone know of a tool that transforms jade code into html? 
As far as I've seen, most of the tools involving jade concentrate on the opposite transformation.

Comment: If the problem is "How do I turn this f'ing HTML into Jade", the solution might be to use this package:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2jade

Comment: You may want to checkout [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) (It's a coding playground that allows you to cross compile JADE, Stylus, and CoffeeScript)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Jade is supposed to come with a command line utility that does exactly that.

See here https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#jade1

Or see just above it for a make file that runs it.

-

Edit - it seems Jade was renamed to Pug - see https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184

but the answer remains - Pug comes with a command line tool - install it with `npm install pug-cli -g`

Then you can run `pug my_template.pug`  which will produce my_template.html

Comment: Ah, that's right! Actually, I can also see some html (the source code of a page) in the browser. Thank you!

Comment: That link is dead.  This is the command line page, and I don't see HTML2Jade as an option: http://jade-lang.com/command-line/

Comment: The link is now pointed to Pug

Answer (score 20):

if you want something online. you can try http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/ or http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Comment: `http://html2jade.org/` - just paste your jade in the `jade` box