# How can i transform Jade files into html?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am starting with Node.js application, so I wanted to take some help from the existing solutions but in views their are always jade files what are they and how can i transform them to html easily?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jade to HTML converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426436/jade-to-html-converter)

Comment: flagged it as a dupe. googling 'what is a jade file' would probably (actually: for sure) tell you what it is. (it's a template file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use EJS for templating other then Jade which provide additional features of HTML. You can configure template on app.js of Express

Answer (score 0):

At http://html2jade.org/ you can paste jade templates into the jade side (on the right) and it will convert it to html (on the left).

(N.B. this functionality does not exist on http://html2pug.org/)

Answer (score 0):

To transform Jade code to Html, you have to install jade compiler in your system and then by using jade CLI you can convert your jade file to Html [Read here](http://jade-lang.com/command-line), But if you not want to install it to system convert it online here [Jade to Html Converter](https://www.adptool.com/jade-to-html).