# How do you convert Jade to HTML files in a web hosting service?

Tags: html, .htaccess, pug, hosting, mime

I am using GoDaddy to host my website, but browsers don't support Jade.  Is there a MIME type or .htaccess file that I can use to convert my Jade files to HTML or get the program to start reading at my index.jade file? Or could I create an index.html file that redirects to my Jade files?

Most other advices have directed me to the HTML2Jade converter, but that is not what I am looking for.  I am trying to run my Jade files as they are, if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: You wanna render all your jade files? Or want to convert to html and use the html files? If so, you could go to Codepen, put your jade in the HTML section, and then select "View HTML compiled". Copy the compíled and make it a new html file. It's a little trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jade to HTML converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426436/jade-to-html-converter)

Comment: Ask GoDaddy. They have #1 Customer Service!

Comment: I want to render all my Jade files.  There are specific things that I can do with Jade, but not HTML  I was on the phone with GoDaddy for an hour today and they could not figure it out.  He just told me that a MIME type or .htaccess file could allow the server to read the Jade files.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using GoDaddy to host my website, but it only reads HTML files.

That isn't true. Even a static hosting site will be able to serve up any kind of file (although it is possible it won't use the right content-type).

If only HTML files were supported then you'd find it very difficult to have webpages that includes images, stylesheets or JavaScript.

> Is there a MIME type or .htaccess file that I can use to convert my Jade files to HTML or get the program to start reading at my index.jade file?

[This](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) suggests that you can use `text/jade` as the MIME type for a Jade file. It [is not standard](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text) though.

Assuming Apache, the [DirectoryIndex directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) can change the default file that is served up for a directory.

This won't do you much good though. **Browsers do not support Jade**, so you have to convert it to HTML first.

> Or could I create an index.html file that redirects to my Jade files?

You could (via meta or JavaScript), but these are terrible approaches and have the same problem.

> Most other advices have directed me to the HTML2Jade converter, but that is not what I am looking for.

It is what you **need** (at least, you need something that converts the Jade into HTML, and preferably something that runs either at build time or server side on demand).

> I am trying to run my Jade files as they are, if this is possible.

It isn't. Browsers don't support Jade.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I understand your point about needing to convert the Jade to HTML, but I still can not find something to use that will actually do this at build time.  With HTML2Jade I could delete all my Jade files and replace them with HTML.  However, this seems unnecessary, defeating the purpose of using Jade in the first place.  Additionally, I use node.js, so if I converted my files to HTML, II would have to redo my work with Handlebars.  Do you know of a file or specific code I could use to convert my Jade to HTML when my site runs?